# Using awk pattern to file filter data

Tags: awk

I have the folling file(named /tmp/test99) which containd the rows:

```
"0","15","wall15"
123132,09808098,"0","15"
```

I am trying to filter the rows that contains "0" in the 3rd place, and "15" in 4th place (like in the second row)
I tried running:

```
cat /tmp/test99 | awk '/"0","15"/{print>"/tmp/0_15_file.out"} '
```

but instead of getting only the second row, I get also the first row starting with `"0","15"`.

Could you please help with the pattern ?
Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check if Fields 3 and 4 are equal to some hardcoded value using

```
awk -F, '$3=="\"0\"" && $4=="\"15\""'
```

Set the field separator to a comma and then, if Field 3 is `"0"` and Field 4 is `"15"` print the line, else discard.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/cTeZ9s):

```
s='"0","15","wall15"
123132,09808098,"0","15"'
awk -F, '$3=="\"0\"" && $4=="\"15\""' <<< "$s" 
# => 123132,09808098,"0","15"
```

Comment: IMHO, I believe OP needs vice versa of this see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53119641/5866580

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 *but instead of getting only the second row* ... OP needs to obtain the second row.

Comment: Sorry but I have read `I am trying to filter the rows that contains "0" in the 3rd place, and "15" in 4th place (like in the second row)`, not an issue let OP come back on same :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.(comment on your effort, you need NOT to use `cat` with `awk` it could read Input_file by itself)

```
awk -F, '$3!~/\"0\"/ && $4!~/\"15\"/' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks, it is an improvement!